# Hibernate criteria orderby

Tags: hibernate, criteria

```
 Criteria crit=hbSession.createCriteria(S1.class)
.add(Restrictions.between("s1Docdt",startDate, endDate))
.add(Restrictions.eq("s1BranchCode",branchCode))    
.add(Restrictions.eq("s1AccountingYear",year));
 crit.addOrder(Order.asc("s1Docdt","s1Dcno","s1Tc");
```

I have created a session and tried to add the restrictions and got an error so can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to Hibernate Javadoc [Order.asc(String)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Order.html#asc%28java.lang.String%29) method, your code seems wrong to me. Try this:

```
Criteria crit = hbSession.createCriteria(S1.class)
    .add(Restrictions.between("s1Docdt",startDate, endDate))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("s1BranchCode",branchCode))    
    .add(Restrictions.eq("s1AccountingYear",year));
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("s1Docdt"));
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("s1Dcno"));
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("s1Tc"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am getting java.lang.ClassCast.exception .i need to know how to resolve this pls

Comment: This is another issue. Ask another question and post your stack trace and your S1 class. We will try to help you.